# mysql: extract Timestamp in separate column as date and time with trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to set a trigger that execute to extract date and time in separate column in a same table when new row insert the table as shown in below:

[image]

What I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_time_insert` 
     BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_raw_attendance 
      FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO tbl_attn_temp (TraineeID, 
                               ScannerID, 
                               attnDate, 
                               attnTime )
             VALUES( NEW.TraineeID, 
                     NEW.ScannerID, 
                     CURRENT_DATE, 
                     CURRENT_TIME );`
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: as I found it's difficult to insert in a same table then I tried to insert with trigger in another table called separate column name but columns name are mismatched. this table have only three columns and the another table have first three columns with date and time column that I want to extract form this timestamp. But undone.

Comment: Add on your question the code you have tried and then we will help you to fix it.

Comment: I'm using this trigger to insert another table `CREATE TRIGGER `date_time_insert` BEFORE INSERT 
ON `tbl_raw_attendance` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO tbl_attn_temp (TraineeID,ScannerID,attnDate,attnTime)
VALUES(NEW.TraineeID, NEW.ScannerID, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME);` but unable to insert in the same table, same way. Thanks